# Java Code Optimization

Tags: java, optimization, graphics

I just did a Tutorial on how to make a character on a 2d background just move around basically like a very limited platformer without gravity or anything and I have run into some lag, Im assuming its because of the way the keypressed/released works but i was wondering if there were any way to optimize it, It could be that I have no animation its just simply a block, but Im not sure, its just like if im holding up and left and then i let go of left and press right while all the time still holding up it just goes up, until i let go, it lags going between left and right etc. I will paste the code below. Thanks!:

```
//@@@MAIN CLASS, NAMED CHECKERS ARBITRARILY

import javax.swing.*;

public class Checkers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("2D Game");

    frame.add(new Board());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1200,326);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}


//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
//class called Dude this is my character(circle)

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class Dude {
int x, dx, y, dy;
Image still;

public Dude(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/still.png");
    still = i.getImage();
    x = 10;
    y = 150;
}

public void move(){
    x = x + dx;
    y = y + dy;

}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public Image getImage(){
    return still;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        dx = -2;

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        dx = 2;

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
       dy = -2;

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
       dy = 2;

}

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
        dx = 0;

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        dx = 0;

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
       dy = 0;

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
       dy = 0;

}

}


//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
//this is my board class (background)



import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

Dude p;
Image img;
Timer time;

public Board(){
    p = new Dude();
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setFocusable(true);
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:/test.png");
    img = i.getImage();
    time = new Timer(5, this);
    time.start();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    p.move();
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.getX(), p.getY(), null);
}

private class AL extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        p.keyReleased(e);
    }
    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
        p.keyPressed(e);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have key repeat on? I.e. are you receiving a bazillion `keyPressed` events?

Comment: You can make your keyPressed and keyReleased methods more optimal with a switch.  Right now all 4 checks must be performed.  This probably won't contribute much to your overall performance, and thats why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
package sof_6406645;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Checkers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("2D Game");

        frame.add(new Board());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1200,326);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        final Image img;
        Point p;
        final boolean[] dynamics = new boolean[4];

        public Board() {
            addKeyListener(new AL());
            setFocusable(true);
            ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("dude.png");
            img = i.getImage();
            p = new Point(0,0);
            Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
            timer.start();
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            moveImage();
        }
        public void moveImage (){
            int dx = 0;
            int dy = 0;
            if(dynamics[0]) dx = -2; 
            if(dynamics[1]) dy = -2; 
            if(dynamics[2]) dx = 2; 
            if(dynamics[3]) dy = 2; 
            p.move((int)p.getX() + dx, (int)p.getY() + dy);
            repaint();
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(img, (int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY(), null);
        }

        private class AL extends KeyAdapter{
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                updateDynamics(e, false);
            }
            public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
                updateDynamics(e, true);
            }
        }
        final void updateDynamics(KeyEvent e, boolean v) {
            int i = e.getKeyCode() - KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
            dynamics[i] = v;
        }
    }
}
```

[edit]:

Made a minor edit to correct the sig on `updateDynamics()` and resisted the urge to manually inline the (effectively) 1 line code that would be duplicated in the two key listener methods.  That method call *should* get inlined by the JIT. The sequence of if statements in `moveImage()` can also be tightened up to halve the checks, but again I am pretty sure the JVM will take care of that for you.

Speaking of the `if`s, I didn't initially change your interaction model, but I would think if you keep pressing two opposing movement keys, `Dude` should stop cold, don't you think?

```
        public void moveImage (){
            int dx = 0;
            int dy = 0;
            if(dynamics[0]) dx -= 2; 
            if(dynamics[1]) dy -= 2; 
            if(dynamics[2]) dx += 2; 
            if(dynamics[3]) dy += 2; 
            p.move((int)p.getX() + dx, (int)p.getY() + dy);
            repaint();
        }
```

Comment: Would Just Like To say Thank You! that worked perfectly and fixed that weird lag I was noticing, you rock, thank you! except 2 things I noticed, with your new moveImage() Method, it works great when stopping, but say both left and right are held down, then you still should be able to move up and down? but you can only move down, and same with up and down, if you hold them both you can only move right, not left...ideas?

Comment: If you sysout the events, you'll note that Swing is not raising the 3rd key events. In your case it seems to have a pattern; on Mac OS X Java 6 SE I don't get events for the 3rd key at all (using arrows) although ctr-alt-shift etc. all raise events as expected.  I don't believe there is an issue with the logic.  (Note I am using the variant moveImage() per above.)